# Are there any mechanisms to detect whether a request is coming from a system level mobile browser?

Tags: android, iphone, http, security

This is a security related question. Say I have an app that can Wants to show a web page served from a webserver. Is there some mechanism for the server to detect whether the request is coming from the system-level browser or from an embedded or in-app browser? Are there any specific headers that the system browsers and/or in-app browsers send, other than the user-agent. Are there any security headers the server can send to block the rendering in in-app browsers?

Comment: Not unless you specifically send one, but you're going at this wrong either way. _Everything_ can be spoofed.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what you consider a "system-level browser" to be. Is Chrome a "system-level browser"? What about Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and its not possible.  You're relying on the client on the remote device sending you accurate data and not lying.  If you're using this for security, you can't do that.  The attacker will lie.  At best, you could eliminate some browsers who are being honest, but you won't be able to eliminate actually malicious attacks like this.

As for sending a security header from the server-  why would any browser honor that?  They'd ignore it instantly.  I'm not even sure what advantage you think you're going to get from this.  Why do you think it matters if its an embedded or non embedded browser?  Why do you think there's any fundamental difference between them?

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure that was the answer. I just wanted to be sure.